# A good resource for finding sound effects and animated clips to use in production for the non experienced

Tags: sound-effects

I am starting to do some semi-professional video production for a software project I have.

I want to know if there is any resource for high quality sound effects and background music and animated clips that you can use in production out there like there is istockphoto.com for photos?

I guess one very important feature (for me at least) is an understandable classification and preview.

By the way I am using Final Cut Pro X if that makes any difference (I know there are lots of sound effects installed with Final Cut and Garage Band and they are great).

Comment: http://www.istockphoto.com/audio ;)

Comment: More sound options [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/2091/741) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sound, check the Freesound Project. http://www.freesound.org/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly what you need, previewable sound effects classified in over 645 categories can be found at [SFXsource Sound Effects Library](http://www.sfxsource.com/sound-effects.html)